# Get a container class instance from a FieldInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, fieldinfo

I am working with C# reflection here:
I have a FieldInfo of a property and I would like to get the instance of the class it belong (so I can reach the content of another property):

for exemple take this class:

```
class MyClass
{
   public int A { get; set; }
   public int B { get; set; }
}
```

in some part of the code I have

```
void Function(FieldInfo fieldInfoOfA)
{
  // here I need to find the value of B
}
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Do you have an object of MyClass in scope at the same time you have fieldInfoOfA in scope?

Comment: I have nothing but this FieldInfo coming from external code. To add some context I'm working with unity's PropertyDrawer (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer-fieldInfo.html), but it's not relevant.

Comment: If you need the value of a field via reflection, check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961781/reflecting-a-private-field-from-a-base-class?rq=1

Comment: FWIW, `A` and `B` on your class are properties, not fields. A FieldInfo would not work for A or for B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible ?

No. Reflection is about discovery of the metadata of a type. A `FieldInfo` does not contain any information about a particular instance of that type. This is why you can get a `FieldInfo` without even creating an instance of the type at all:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetField(...)
```

Given the snippet above, you can see that a `FieldInfo` can be obtained without any dependence on a particular instance.

Answer (score 2):

`FieldInfo` provides access to the metadata for a field within a class, it is independent of a specified instance.

If you have an instance of `MyClass` you can do this:

```
object Function(MyClass obj, FieldInfo fieldInfoOfA)
{
    var declaringType = fieldInfoOfA.DeclaringType;

    var fieldInfoOfB = declaringType.GetField("B");

    return fieldInfoOfB.GetValue(obj);
}
```