# Universal classes field parser to Dictionary<String, String> using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a lot of times thinking about converting example of class to `Dictionary<String, String>` where key is variable name(class field name) and value is variable current assigned value. So we have a simple class:

```
public class Student
{
    public String field1;
    public Int64 field2;
    public Double field3;
    public Decimal field4;

    public String SomeClassMethod1()
    {
        ...
    }
    public Boolean SomeClassMethod2()
    {
        ...
    }
    public Int64 SomeClassMethod1()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How I expect it will look like:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Student student = new Student(){field1 = "", field2 = 3, field3 = 3.0, field4 = 4.55m};
    Dictionary<String, String> studentInDictionary = ConvertAnyToDictionary<Student>(student);
}

public Dictionary<String, String> ConvertAnyToDictionary<T>(T value) where T:class
{
...
}
```

Any ideas about how to make it real? Thx a lot for any advices.

EDIT1:
Expected result:

```
studentInDictionary[0] = KeyValuePair("field1", "");
studentInDictionary[1] = KeyValuePair("field2", (3).ToString());
studentInDictionary[2] = KeyValuePair("field3", (3.0).ToString());
studentInDictionary[3] = KeyValuePair("field4", (4.55m).ToString());
```

Comment: What is the expected output for that code?

Comment: @Maris - if you think about it, JSON is a dictionary of strings, so what you want is very simmilar to a JSON Serializer. So don't reinvent the wheel if you don't really need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
public static Dictionary<String, String> ConvertAnyToDictionary<T>(T value) where T : class {
    var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    var dict1 = fields.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(value).ToString());
    var dict2 = properties.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(value, null).ToString());

    return dict1.Union(dict2).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Value);
}
```

**Edit**: I'm taking in count both *fields* and *properties* there. If you will only be using properties, you can just use `dict2`.

You might want to take a look at the `BindingFlags` argument received by `GetFields()` and `GetProperties()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var proInfos = student.GetType().GetProperties();

          if(proInfos!=null)
             {
                   Dictionary<string,string> dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();


             foreach (var propertyInfo in proInfos)
             {
                var tv = propertyInfo.GetValue(currentObj, null);

                 if(tv!=null)
                 {
                    if(dict.ContainsKey(propertyInfo.Name))
                        continue;

                    dict.Add(propertyInfo.Name, tv.ToString());
                 }


                }
             }
```

Comment: The `Student` class does not contain any *property*.

Comment: Oh, I can add the {get;set;}

Comment: @Maris : You can add get and set to mark the fields as properties also why you want to do this , if you need to assign the values between your model and DTO objects then please consider AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can either serialize using already existing Serializers (Xml or JSON) or you can go about it using reflection.

Here is an example of how to get fields with reflection:

[Not getting fields from GetType().GetFields with BindingFlag.Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155529/c-sharp-gettype-getfields-problem)

Comment: I dont think serializing class to JSON/Xml, then deserializing it to the Dictionary<String,String> is a good idea. The problem is not in getting all field names, but the problem is getting values assigned to the current examplar of the class fields.

Comment: @Maris I was thinking the resulting JSON would suffice, you actually need to obtain the final form of KeyValuePairs? If yes, then go the Reflection path. Obtain all fields as FieldInfo[] and extract from there the name and value.